# Trying to get property of non-object laravel using color-extractor

Tags: php, laravel, colors

I am currently working with laravel and I used a color extractor from github to get the three most prominent colors from a picture (jpg or png). This works, check PrtSc:

[image: Color extractor picture]

As you can see the hexa-codes are links, when you click the link you should see every article where the hexacode is one of the most prominent colors.
When I click the link I get a "trying to get property of non-object" error.

This is the function in my controller to get al the articles:

```
public function getTag($tag)
{

    $articles = Article::where('tags', 'LIKE', '%'.$tag.'%')->get();


    return view("article.tagFilter")->with('articles',$articles);
}

public function getColor($color)
{
    $articles = Article::where('color', 'LIKE', '%'.$color.'%')->get();


    return view("article.tagFilter")->with('articles',$articles);
}
```

The function getTag is exactly the same and this function does work.

This is the function where I load the view you can see on the image above.

```
public function showArticle($id)
{
    $article = Article::find($id);
    $comments = DB::table('comments')
                ->select('*')
                ->where('article_id', '=', $id)
                ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'user_id')
                ->get();
    $myString = $article->tags;
    $myColorString = $article->color;
    $myArray = explode(',', $myString);
    $myColorArray = explode(',',$myColorString);

    return view('article.show')->with('article',$article)>with('myArray',$myArray)->with('comments',$comments)->with('myColorArray',$myColorArray);
}
```

This is the part of the view where I show the hexacodes:

```
 <?php
for ($i = 0; $i < count($myColorArray); ++$i) {

?><a href="/articles/color/{{$myColorArray[$i]}}"><p>

        <?php
        print "#".$myColorArray[$i];
        ?>

    </p></a>
<?php
}
?>
```

And last but not least the route I use:

```
Route::get('articles/color/{color}','TagController@getColor');
```

I hope you guys can help me!

Comment: On what line of what file do you get the property of non-object error?

Comment: the $myString = $article->tags; in the showArticle function. But the funny thing is that I can filter on the tags in this case "flopsie" but I cant filter on the colors

Comment: Your route calls `getColor`, but you're saying that `showArticle` is the problem?

Comment: I dont know where the problem is, the error says showarticle is the problem. But showarticle is the function to show what you can see on the image, so, this function works. When I click the link flopsie, it shows me every article with the "flopsie"-tag. The getTag function does this. I made almost the same function to show every article whit the same color, but this does not work. I get the error when I click the link of a color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my error. When I clicked the link laravel thought I was going to another route. It used the one below:

```
Route::get('articles/{id}/{title}', 'HomeController@showArticle');
```

Although my other route was above this one in the list. I had to put the route to the tagController@getColor all the way on top.